# UITableViewController delegate gives error in swift

Tags: iphone, swift

I am getting the error below while making a simple code for UITableView in Swift Xcode 6.1

```
/Users/classic/Documents/CIPL/Demo Projects/DemoTableView/DemoTableView/ViewController.swift:11:1: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

/Users/classic/Documents/CIPL/Demo Projects/DemoTableView/UIKit.UITableViewDataSource:3:48: Protocol requires function 'tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)' with type '(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell'
```

Anyone knows why this issue is occurring ?

Comment: Did you define your TableViewController in your Storyboard as a Subclass of UITableViewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declared the mandatory functions of UITableVIewDataSource protocol in your class ?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement all mandatory protocol method for tableview.

```
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayData.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// Define your cell and return it
}
```